# How do I search a text field and extract everything after a keyword until an end of line "/n"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a large and inconsistent block of text (I am testing using OCR and a random print out, but my final code will be using a driving license or other form of ID)

I want to search the text for a keyword like "name" or "1)" then extract everything "AFTER" that keyword, until I reach a break point or end of line.

I am currently using:

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"name: (.*?) Smith" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

            [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:tesseractText.text
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, tesseractText.text.length)
                                  usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
             {
                 NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
                 tesseractText.text = [tesseractText.text substringWithRange:group1]; // changes textField to value of specific text
             }
             ];
```

This works when extracting just the first name (for example, George), but when I tried to get the "Smith" I tried

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"name: (.*?) /n"
```

and

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"name: (.*?) "
```

but neither work :(

I because I am using OCR, the camera won't always catch "everything" and because the typical ID places each piece of information on a new line, I don't have a "key" in order to capture the in between text, so I either need to get the text "until an end-of-line" or new paragraph, or less optimally, a fixed number of characters after keyword "name: " it won't take into account varying name lengths, but at least it will work to some extent.

In the event of using fixed number of characters after name: to avoid out of bounds, I'll probably need to count the characters in a line, but again, because this is a textfield and not a single line label, I'll need to count "just" the characters in that line and not the next one.

If the code I used could be tweaked that'd be great, but if there's a completely different method using Objective C then I am willing to rewrite what I've done so far to get this feature working

Thanks for you time

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string that you're trying to parse with this regular expression?

Comment: Did you really use `/n` (forward-slash, n)? That's not a newline. You presumably meant `\n` (back-slash, n). Alternatively, you can remove the question mark from your regular expression. That makes the `*` non-greedy. If you allow it to be greedy, it will pick up everything to the newline or end-of-string.

Comment: Let me check, i might have used / instead of \, i'll see if that works

@PaulPatterson the string I have for testing is
"...tions and proof of concept.
...t numbers, there will be three teams"
The camera sometimes cuts out text, hence the ... and the word I am trying to get is "concept" if it works in this example, it will work with all. 
(I don't have the item I want to scan yet, but the format will be like this:)
1. WILLS
2. MATTHEW DAVID

3. 039371 UNITED KINGDOM
.
.
.
(etc)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ken Thomases, I solved the problem, my code works fine, but I used /n instead of \n

so:

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"name: (.*?) \n" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

works, but I have a new problem which I will post as a new question
If the "Key" is a number, it won't work, for example

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"1 (.*?) \n" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

It returns an error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRIT" this is problematic since the keys that occur on a driving licence are all numbers... So now I must look for alternatives